# How make a ListPreference with checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, preference, listpreference

How can I create a `ListPreference` with `checkbox`?
I know how to use `ListPreference`, but I need multiple selection like in Alarm application on "repeat" preference.

like this screenshot:

[image: checkboxes]

Answer (score 21):

Since API 11 you can use MultiSelectListPreference

```
String[] selections = {"selection1","Selection2"};
Set<String> selectionSet = new HashSet<String>();
selectionSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(selections));

MultiSelectListPreference multiSelectPref = new MultiSelectListPreference(this);
        multiSelectPref.setKey("multi_pref");
        multiSelectPref.setTitle("Multi Select List  Preference");
        multiSelectPref.setEntries(selections);
        multiSelectPref.setEntryValues(selections);
        multiSelectPref.setDefaultValue(selectionSet);
        getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(multiSelectPref);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use, MultiSelectListPreference

```
<MultiSelectListPreference
        app:defaultValue="@array/watermark_entries_view"
        app:dialogTitle="Select Watermark Type"
        app:entries="@array/watermark_entries_view"
        app:entryValues="@array/watermark_entries_values"
        app:key="mode_repeat"
        app:summary="Enable Watermark"
        app:title="Watermark" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in preference for that AFAIK. `ListPreference` is single-select only.

You could create your own custom `Preference` class, though, by extending `DialogPreference`.

Answer (score 0):

For boolean values you must use a SwitchPreference, as follows:

```
  <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="example_switch"
        android:summary="@string/pref_description_social_recommendations"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_social_recommendations" />
```